# Meteor deployed app changes visual scale

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

My problem is pretty straightforward, but very mysterious nonetheless.
What happens is when I deploy my Meteor app with `meteor deploy <domain>` the UI is actually a little smaller than the localhost version. Everything is equal, except for the fact that everything is reduced in size by about 10%.

Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are certain with your browser's settings? Also I suggest you to check your browser's console and network panel if you use a script domain specific or including a css from a third party. Other then these, would be nice to have the domain to check. Best.

Comment: That's because it's minified when sent to the server :) More seriously, you must be zoomed in/out on your browser.

Comment: The zoom did it. I'm struggling to describe how dumb*** I'm feeling right now.